# Child pages with same slug

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

The client I am currently working for is asking for a link structure like so:

```
theirsite.com/industries/auto/sales-effectiveness-calculator
theirsite.com/industries/cable_satellite/sales-effectiveness-calculator
theirsite.com/industries/insurance/sales-effectiveness-calculator
theirsite.com/industries/home_services/sales-effectiveness-calculator
theirsite.com/industries/hotels_cruises/sales-effectiveness-calculator
theirsite.com/industries/wireless_carriers/sales-effectiveness-calculator
```

In this scenario, the child page '**sales-effectiveness-calculator**' obviously has the same page slug as all the others. I understand Wordpress won't allow this by default, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with rewrite rules or by using permalink structure, etc. Anybody have any ideas?

One note is that the page sales-effectiveness-calculator will have the same content regardless of it's parent page (just a couple different labels I can change with jQuery) so if there's a way to point to the same page but show the URL as above, that would work too.

I've tried to convince them otherwise, but they really like this structure for various reason, and I want to exhaust all possibilities before I end up just telling them it's completely not possible.

thanks

Comment: Huge question @Eckstein!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of being able to create that URL structure, it is definitely possible. If you are assigning those pages to a parent, it will allow you to have the same slug, as long as they all have different parents.

I would definitely recommend that they don't have the same content on each though, as this would have a detrimental effect within your search rankings, as it would be classed as duplicate content.

Comment: Huh, you're right, it worked fine. Maybe I was reading info from an old Wordpress version.

I'm doing this via plugin and I think I will be using a shortcode with a couple parameters to show the calculator on each page, that way I'm not truly duplicating content. Plus, these are not really meant to be found via search, the main industry pages are.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Great, I am glad this is resolved now.